# Will there ever be a case where x+1<x

Tags: number-theory

I was thinking, is there any values that will satisfy $x$ where $(x+1)<x$ ?

If there is. what is it and what is the proof?

If there isn't, why and how can you prove that it will never be?

Comment: You could just say if that's the case, then you would have $1<0$ which is ridiculous. What are your assumptions though?

Comment: I can't think of an example  considering the "default" field. What are your assumptions about the field you're working on?

Comment: Maybe you should specify in which ring or set you are working, and what order you want to use.

Comment: If you are working on real number set,it will never happen as1<0.But if you define your own set or group,thats different thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You only have to redefine some combination of  "+", "<", and the domain of $x$. But with $x \in \mathbb R$ and $``+"$ and $``<"$ having the usual meaning, no, there aren't any values $x$ where $(x + 1) < x$.

But, just to show an example, Define $\mathbb W_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and define $``+"$ and $``<"$ as follows.

```
 + | 0 1 2 3 4          0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4
---+-----------
 0 | 0 1 2 3 4
 1 | 1 2 3 4 0
 2 | 2 3 4 0 1
 3 | 3 4 0 1 2
 4 | 4 0 1 2 3

Then 4 + 1 = 0 and  0 < 4.
```

Comment: Nice judicious choice of interpretation of the question, +1

Comment: Well answered. Was what I was looking for! Thanks :)